# How to install gcc 4.4.6 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, x86-64

I have read that GCC 4.4.6 is packaged in the Ubuntu release 11.10 (Oneiric). My question is how to install it using apt-get because `apt-get install gcc446` doesn't work neither `apt-get install gcc44.`

Comment: What error do you get? Have you checked the package name using `apt-cache search gcc`?

Comment: I think that question would be more appropriate on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: This question may have already been resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619236/ubuntu-11-04-installing-gcc-4-4-6

Answer (score 2):

step 1: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Step 2: sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4

Step 3: Check the installed version by 
                sudo gcc -v

Comment: I then had to manually modify the symbolic link "gcc" to point to "gcc-4.4" because the build-essential installed "gcc-4.6"

Answer (score 1):

It installed successfully with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a metapackage called build-essential which should install the compiler and a bunch of related/needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

The suggestion to first do sudo apt-get update is sound, this will update package lists and all versions should match nicely.

That is, however, if you didn't modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file manually. If so, then maybe some of the changes you made or repositories you added contain conflicting packages which cause the problems you see. If that's the case, please look at the file and fix the troublesome entries. Of course, if you want help doing so, you can post your `sources.list` file (or any fragments in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`) and maybe someone can help you fix them.